# Jfrog-CLI installation isn't working

Tags: installation, artifactory, artifact, jfrog-cli

I'm running it on Ubuntu.
when I try to run: `npm install -g jfrog-cli-go`

I get:

[image: Error For Running NPM Command]

And when I try the other option of running it using curl, it gives the feeling like it succeeded but when I try to run

```
> jfrog
```

it doesn't recognize the command `curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh`
I get:

[image: Error For Running Curl Command]

the jfrog-cli version that I'm using is: 1.17.1

Can anyone tell me what's the problem here?

Comment: Any additional information in the npm debug log?

Comment: Have you tried `./jfrog` instead of `jfrog`?

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky no, thats it.

Comment: @DarthFennec yes, still nothing

Comment: look at the correct answer that @yahavi answered me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**npm:**
For npm in Ubuntu please use `--unsafe-perm=true` flag:
`sudo npm install -g jfrog-cli-go --unsafe-perm=true`.
Please see the [npm package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jfrog-cli-go) for more info.

**curl:** Curl will download jfrog cli to your current working directory. After this, you can either run it locally by running `./jfrog` or moving it to Ubuntu's execution path, e.g. `sudo mv ./jfrog /usr/local/bin/`